# Tumblr is visiting my blog?

Tags: traffic, tumblr

I have created a blog on Tumblr a few days ago. Looking over the statistics, it seems that Tumblr itself is visiting my website, using different browsers. What is this supposed to mean? Are these real visitors or is it a Tumblr bot? One example:

- Browser: Chrome 32.0
- OS: Win8
- Resolution: 1024x768
- Location: New York, United States
- IP Address: Tumblr (66.6.40.249)
- Referring URL: (No referring link)

Other browsers used include:

- Chrome 20.0.1090.0
- Firefox 21
- Opera 12.14
- Chrome 15.0.861.0
- Chrome 32.0.1667.0
- Internet Explorer 6
- Internet Explorer 9
- Opera 12
- Opera 12.02

They *all* use the same screen resolution (1024x768) and have no referrer. The Flash version is not set, but they do support JavaScript. Unfortunately, I don't have the full user agent string.

Comment: Do you have the full user agent string?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't.

Comment: What is the URL to your blog?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything that indicated that Tumblr has a crawler. And typically "good" crawlers usually identify themselves as such. So this is probably just someone at Tumblr either viewing or reviewing your blog.

Answer (score 1):

Did you possibly ask them for support?

The Whois info for that IP is http://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=66.6.40.249?showDetails=true&showARIN=false&ext=netref2.

Comment: You should mention the result of the whois so we don't have to follow the link. Plus the IP is from Tumbler.

Answer (score 0):

How do you think internal Tumblr staff patrol their own sites? By visiting them to review content.

I would not take it personally. Most likely someone clicking through thousands of posts per day. Given the array of browsers it could all be quality assurance checks or the IP address is just a firewall gateway masking employee access.

But after saying that my gut tells me that if all of the screen sizes are `1024x768` then it is most likely an internal quality assurance crawler that is just doing it’s rounds across all of the Tumblr sites to make sure themes don’t break or other QA related tasks.  I bet the crawler doing this just compiles screenshots or snapshots of page content, and then some QA person cracks open a soda and clicks through piles of them looking for content breaking. Content breaks in a template? Well then that goes back to design & engineering to fix the issue.